# Can I control where windows open in Gnome Classic?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gui, gnome-classic

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric with Gnome Classic and Compiz.

When I open some applications, they appear near the top of the screen, underneath the top panel. This means I can't grab the to bar of the window to move them.

Is there a way I can prevent this, either by controlling where the default space on the desktop is to open new windows, or by creating some space around the top panel which they can't go into?

Comment: You can press ALT+mouse and click and hold anywhere on the window to move it.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good tip. Still need to find a way to get them to just open in the right place, though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compiz plugin that can handle window placement. Called "place". You can read more about it [here](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place) and how to set it up.